# Accessing Azure SQL from Web App with EF Core, Docker and System Assigned Identity

Tags: sql-server, azure, entity-framework, docker, .net-core

I'm trying to access a serverless azure SQL database from an Azure Web Application running a docker container under Linux. The container is a .Net Core 3.1 web application using the latest EF Core. The web app has been configured to use a system assigned identity.

For the SQL user, I use the following PS script to get an SID, where the object ID is the system assigned identity object ID:

```
$principal = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $objectId
 
foreach ($byte in $principal.ApplicationId.ToByteArray())
{
    $byteGuid += [System.String]::Format("{0:X2}", $byte)
}
 
$sid = "0x" + $byteGuid
```

Then, I created the user with db_owner role to the database using the SID like this...
`'CREATE USER [AppUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo], SID=' + '$(AppSiD)' + ' , TYPE = E'`
...similar to the process described here:
https://blog.bredvid.no/handling-azure-managed-identity-access-to-azure-sql-in-an-azure-devops-pipeline-1e74e1beb10b

I've also updated the EF instance using the following method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi#modify-aspnet-core

When the application tried to access the DB, the following exception is thrown:
`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'.`
**EDIT** I don't believe the SQL user to be causing the issue, as the error occurs whether the user exists or not.

I'd prefer to fix the error above but if there is is an alternative way to connect to the DB without using a SQL user I would appreciate the advice.

Thanks

**EDIT**
Elaborated on the SQL user process as the link is down at the time of posting

Comment: not sure what you mean by SID (and the link is broken), but you should have added the SQL user like this: `CREATE USER [<identity-name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;`

Comment: Hi @silent,
Thanks for your reply. I'm unable to add a user in that way as it's not connected to AD: `Principal 'AppUser' could not be created. Only connections established with Active Directory accounts can create other Active Directory users.` I've updated the question with more information

Comment: I've just found out that the error occurs whether the user is added or not

Comment: well if your SQL database is not AAD enabled, this will not work to begin with

Comment: Thanks @silent adding the user with your original script worked. If you want to add it as an answer i'll mark it the answer.
Cheers

Comment: Sure, will do later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make your SQL database [AAD-enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell). Then you can create a user for your Managed Identity like this

```
CREATE USER [<identity-name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

And then of course assign permissions to that user as needed.